# Rails iteration for fields in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration

i would like to iterate out some field names, appending the index number to the name of the field e.g. `claim_1`, `claim_2`, `claim_3` etc

Simplified view:

```
<% (1..4).each_with_index do |index| %>
    <%= f.label :claims_index %> 
<% end %>
```

How can I get the index to be either 1, 2, 3, 4 or whatever respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need `each_with_index` iterator for this -

```
<% 1.upto(4) do |i| %>
  <%= f.label "claims_#{i}" %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% (1..4).each_with_index do |index| %>
    <%= f.label "claim_#{index}" %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you're after but each_with_index takes two arguments so you could do:

```
<% @claims.each_with_index do |claim,index| %>
   <%= "#{index+1}: #{claim.name}" %>
<% end %>
```

Which will print out each claim name and the index (1,2,3,4) The +1 makes it 1 based, rather than 0 based.

Alteranatively, simply use:

```
<% (1..4).each do |i| %>
  <%= i %>
<% end %>
```